# 802.11ac Support in Fedora 20 (or any latest linux distro)

Tags: wifi, distributions, 802.1x

I bought a new HP Envy jt100 laptop (with an upgraded wireless card -- 802.11ac). The default OpenSUSE distro doesn't recognize the wireless card! I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to fix it, but meanwhile I want to ask the following:

Do you know which Linux distro supports 802.11ac out of the box?

Wireless Card:
Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

Comment: What card are you using? It is difficult to recommend what you need to do without knowing what hardware you have.  If you don't know its name or chipset, copy the output of `lspci` into your post (at least the relevant lines).

Comment: Sorry for excluding the most important info...I updated the original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

- http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/wireless/492448-help-resolve-wifi-issue-broadcom-bcm4352-14e4-43b1-opensuse-13-1-a.html

In short:

1. Install http://packman.links2linux.de/download/broadcom-wl/1568712/broadcom-wl-kmp-desktop-6.30.223.141_k3.11.6_4-2.6.x86_64.rpm
2. Install http://packman.links2linux.de/download/broadcom-wl/1568714/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.141-2.6.x86_64.rpm
3. Reboot

If you're using Fedora, please note slm's answer.

Comment: This will work for SuSE but I do not believe you can mix the RPMs from SuSE with Fedora. You can try but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: For example, though this isn't a huge deal, the location that the contents of the 2nd RPM installs is not a standard location on Fedora, for example: `/usr/share/doc/packages/broadcom-wl`.

Comment: I'm actually using opensuse as the default distro

Comment: BTW I can definitely confirm that this works on OpenSuse 13.1 -- I just installed the rpms and wifi started working.

Comment: The title of the Q mentions Fedora. This solves the Q in the body.

Comment: The title mentions Fedora and then adds "or any latest distro". I would settle for any distro which has the solution. OpenSuse is the first one I've found. But I do appreciate your help -- I used it to get to the opensuse forum.

Comment: Sure, I'm just trying to figure out how to best present a solution to your Q. The answers is split b/w the 2 of us, and I don't know how to frame the A any better. I would mark yours as the accepted answer when you can, but you might want to absorb some of the info in the comments into the answer so it's clearer to others that might come across this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is often the case with newer hardware. There is already an issue open about this in Fedora bug tracker and there are several workarounds listed there.

See this issue: [Bug 1027651 - Wireless driver for Broadcom BCM4352 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.95](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1027651).

There is also mention of a [driver hosted on Canonical](http://people.canonical.com/~ypwong/drivers/broadcom/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_95.tar.gz), assuming it's the right version for your particular hardware.

Since that driver is hosted on Canonical, I'd expect Ubuntu might be a good place to start, if you're looking for an out of box distro to have it, though they might be just pulling things together for a future release with that driver.

Comment: I guess that's the best answer so far...I'll wait a day and accept it if nobody else can provide an easier solution than what's in that forum. Thanks!!

Comment: @Vladimir - you might want to make your Q more specific or expand it. The title says Fedora, the body says OpenSUSE.